# Can you die of starvation while in a catatonic state as a result of magic jar?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, food-and-drink

Can you die of starvation while in a catatonic state as a result of magic jar? If yes, in how many days? Is it possible force-feed someone while they're in this catatonic state?

Comment: How did the person in question come to be in a catatonic state?

Comment: Using magic jar, for example

Comment: Are you specifically interested in Magic Jar, or are there other effects that cause catatonia that your question is also about?

Comment: I'm interested in the catatonia induced by magic jar, but I thought that this problem about the condition of being catatonic was independent by his cause.

Comment: When magic is involved, the cause of a condition can be **very** important.

Comment: But *the problem is not about removing it*, the time that you need for starving while in catatonic state should be always the same (at first order at least) and the same should be about force-fedding

Comment: If you asked the specific question "Can you die of starvation while in a catatonic state as a result of magic jar?" You'll likely get a more general answer that will address the concerns of catatonia generally. I would recommend possibly rewording that way to allow the question to be reopened. Magic Jar is the only thing I can find that even causes this state, so there likely is no real need for a generic question regardless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## RAW - you can probably die of starvation (DM decision)

There are no rules for what defines the catatonic state so the DM would have to make a ruling regarding whether the body still needs to eat.

*Magic jar* does give some information that might help with this determination. It says that your body can indeed die even while your soul is separated from it:

> if your body is dead when you attempt to return to it

So, it seems reasonable to infer from this that the body is alive and must require some sort of upkeep to keep alive. In this case, it would seem reasonable to think that feeding is part of this required upkeep.

## There are no rules for forced feeding

Similarly there are no rules for forced feeding so it would be up to your DM to rule if the catatonic body could be fed and how. If you can get the person to somehow eat even a
single *goodberry* a day that will be enough to feed them. Otherwise:

> A character needs one pound of food per day

## Dying of hunger

If your DM rules that feeding is necessary:

> A character can go without food for a number of days equal to 3 + his or her Constitution modifier (minimum 1). At the end of each day beyond that limit, a character automatically suffers one level of exhaustion. ([D&DB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/adventuring#FoodandWater))

The [exhausted condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Exhaustion) escalates with each level of exhaustion you get. At 6 exhaustion you die.

So, your character would last 3+(Con Mod)+6 days without food.

## Dying of thirst

However, you should be more concerned with getting water into the body. All the above assumed that the body had access to water but just no food.

> A character with access to even less [than 1 gallon of] water automatically suffers one level of exhaustion at the end of the day.
>
> If the character already has one or more levels of exhaustion, the
> character takes two levels in either case. ([D&DB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/adventuring#FoodandWater))

Without any water the body will die of exhaustion after 4 days total (significantly less than it takes for the body to die from hunger).

## Rules as Intended - no food or water is needed

Jeremy Crawford has provided guidance on this issue via this [tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/805224172288753666):

> Magic jar doesn't specify whether your body requires food/drink/air while you're away. RAW: Up to the DM. RAI: None are required.

How much you want to adhere or apply this guidance to the rules at your table is up to your DM.

Comment: Actually "catatonic" is defined  - it takes its Normal English meaning "abnormality of movement and behaviour arising from a disturbed mental state (typically schizophrenia). It may involve repetitive or purposeless overactivity, or catalepsy, resistance to passive movement, and negativism." - it is not suspended animation so you need to eat and drink.

Comment: @DaleM I never said it wasn't, just that there were no rules that defined it. But yeah you are correct. The problem is that catatonia seems to encompass a wide variety of symptoms so I didn't really get into the real world definition for that reason.

Comment: I raise it because the OP may not be aware of what "catatonic" actually means and the problem may vanish if they are made aware.

Comment: @DaleM fair point. I guess I was just explaining why I included it. I think it was a valuable clarification and I appreciate it. Sorry if it came across otherwise. :)

Comment: The problem wan not just about die of starvation while in catatonic state but also about force-feeding, maybe I was missing something, but seems you agree about its possibility